# How to store an int and boolean as a pair

Tags: java, memory-management, primitive-types

We have a number of properties in several classes where the property is presently an int and a boolean. The int is the value and the boolean is true if that int has been set.

We need this pairing because we are representing an object that has levels of properties where if it is not set at one level, it uses the setting at the level above. This approach lets us record at each level what its value is and if it was set at that level or inherited.

It works great. However we can end up with literally 100,000 of these objects. And that's a ton of memory, a ton of garbage collection, etc. So, any ideas how we can somehow do this better. We looked at an array of ints and booleans with enums as the index. But that feels really awkward, which generally means more opportunities to get something wrong (ie introduce bugs).

Any suggestions?

thanks - dave

Comment: You could use an Integer (which could be null if not set)?

Comment: You can't just use Integer instead of int? 100,000 objects doesn't sound like too much. What is the total memory footprint?

Comment: It's both the ton of objects which takes up memory and the processing around the garbage collection as these tend to live for an intermediate length of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most answers here already cover what I would initially suggest, but if it's just a matter of garbage collector pressure and not so much memory footprint, and you really need the full range of 32 bit ints, you could apply the same kind of bit-masking tricks with a long instead.

You would have a utility class that has functions like

```
long setIntValue(int i) { return 0xFFFF0000 | i; }
int getIntValue(long l) { return (int)(0xFFFF & l); }
boolean isIntValueSet(long l) { return (0xFFFF0000 & l) != 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, yes. As I commented to @user949300 - this could work very well. I'm thinking use 0x08000000 so masking it out I still get positive and negative numbers.

Comment: I don't have Eclipse at hand to verify how the bitmask and cast handle negative numbers, and it's subtle enough I'd want to verify rather than speculate, but if that implementation doesn't do what you want I'd suggest keeping the intermediate value as a long a bit longer and doing the negative bit check yourself, rather than putting it into the mask.

Answer (score 7):

If you are not using the full range of the `int`, you can use a magic value like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or `-1` to represent "not set".

An example of this would be String's `indexOf()` method which will return `-1` if it did not find a match.

Comment: We first started with that approach. But we found that we need to have the value at each level (set from the parent when it is the "set" one) so the int value is set and we can't use a magic number.

Answer (score 3):

Are the ints positive and in order (or, if not in order, they don't go up to huge values)?  i.e. 1,2,3,4...99999,100000?

If so, you could use a [java.util.BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

Comment: That could work! We would use the bit 0x08000000 and when we mask that out we have a 31-bit int that handles positive and negative numbers!

Comment: The size of the BitSet depends on the largest integer that is set, divided by 8.  If you are setting 2^31 it will be huge. (I think 2^28 bytes).  But if the maximum int you ever set is 100,000 it will only be 12.5K bytes.

Comment: @David, the value you would use for the bit value is `0x40000000`, leaving the sign intact resulting in a range of `0xbfffffff` to `0x3fffffff`.

Answer (score 2):

2 posibilities come to mind,

- use `Integer` objects and use a `null` reference to specify that the value has not been set.
- if the `int`s value range does not span the whole range you could choose a value like `Integer.MIN_INT` to specify that the value has not been set.

Comment: The Integer approach has the same problem - we need to have the correct value at each level.

Comment: @David, is getting the parent's value when the Integer reference is null (can be done in the getter) too slow?

Comment: getting the parent would have to be called a lot so over the total, yes very slow. It also would require we pass in the complete tree of ancestors so we could walk up looking for the set value and that means passing more.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a touple class

```
public class Tuple<X,Y>{
    private final X x;
    private final Y y;

    public Tuple(X x,Y y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public X getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public Y getY(){
        return y;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An int[] and boolean[] with 100K elements each will use about 500K of memory (and is two objects)

You could use a `int` value to store the flag as well. But if that not an option youc an use a `long` which can store all possible int and boolean values.

You can use a collection like an `int[]` or `long[]` or even an `int[]` and a `boolean[]` i.e. store the data in a column based instead of row based structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Pair<L,R>`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) from apache.commons.lang. You are doing [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) without any facts proving that there is indeed a performance/memory problem caused by those pairs.

Comment: definitely not premature optimization. This is about 18% of our total memory footprint.